# What is the meaning of Haskell error: Required ancestor ‘A’ not found for type ‘B’

Tags: haskell

What is the meaning of Haskell error like:

> Required ancestor ‘A’ not found for type ‘B’.

Comment: Please include more context: minimal reproducible example, and what compiler and os you are using (because I've never seen this error!)

Comment: Worth pointing out that a [search for `Haskell <the above error>`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=haskell+Required+ancestor+‘A’+not+found+for+type+‘B’) yields the relevant link almost immediately. Lots of Haskell stuff is open source, you can normally find the error message directly in the source then work out what's gone wrong from that.

Comment: @hnefatl, you are right about the search, but you forget I am a new user and what I saw did not make sense to me. How do I know if the error is my fault, or is is a library bug or ghc bug or something else.

Comment: @ruby_object It's not at all clear from your question what proficiency you have with Haskell, but given the source of the error it was reasonable to assume you were not a beginner.

Comment: I am a beginner. At the moment I am evaluating a feasibility of using Haskell for the project I have in mind. In order to know if it is worth to spend my time learning Haskell I need to evaluate one of the neglected corners of GUI programming where all languages that I have tried struggle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a Haskell error; that's a custom message from the [Data.GI.Base.Overloading](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-gi-base-0.20.8/docs/Data-GI-Base-Overloading.html) module:

https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi/blob/0c66d9ebab48285c22a96fb0221d8d77d78beaba/base/Data/GI/Base/Overloading.hs#L87-L106

```
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,9,0)
-- | Type error to be generated when an ancestor check fails.
type family UnknownAncestorError (a :: *) (t :: *) where
    UnknownAncestorError a t =
        TypeError ('Text "Required ancestor ‘" ':<>: 'ShowType a
                   ':<>: 'Text "’ not found for type ‘"
                   ':<>: 'ShowType t ':<>: 'Text "’.")
#endif

-- | Check whether a type appears in a list. We specialize the
-- names/types a bit so the error messages are more informative.
type family CheckForAncestorType t (a :: *) (as :: [*]) :: AncestorCheck * * where
    CheckForAncestorType t a '[] =
#if !MIN_VERSION_base(4,9,0)
        'DoesNotHaveRequiredAncestor "Error: Required ancestor" a "not found for type" t
#else
        UnknownAncestorError a t
#endif
    CheckForAncestorType t a (a ': as) = 'HasAncestor a t
    CheckForAncestorType t a (b ': as) = CheckForAncestorType t a as
```

Comment: Finally, I have figured it out. Function castTo was the missing link.  More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979509/how-do-i-cast-widget-to-label-in-haskells-gi-gtk

Comment: @ruby_object I am having a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76586787/how-to-create-a-pixbuf-from-bytestring-in-gtks-haskell-bindings. Since you figured it out, could please take a look at my question?

Comment: That was 6 years ago. I have forgotten what it was all about. I do not use Haskell much these days. :-(