# How to create a Pixbuf from ByteString in GTK's Haskell bindings?

Tags: haskell, gtk3

Here is the code:

```hs
  let myFile = $(embedFile "img/termonad-lambda.png")
  let wordsss = unpack myFile
  img_ptr <- mallocBytes (length wordsss)
  forM_ (zip wordsss [0 ..]) $ \(word8, off) ->
    pokeByteOff img_ptr off (CUChar word8)
  pb <- pixbufNewFromData img_ptr ColorspaceRgb False 8 50 50 (50 * 3)
  GI.Gtk.Objects.Window.windowSetDefaultIcon pb
```

It uses GTK binding for Haskell for some GUI program.
At the last line, I am trying to set an icon for the main window.
That function accepts a `Pixbuf`.
I am getting the `Pixbuf` from a `ByteString`. The first line embeds (using [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed) library) an image into the binary, at compile time, as a `ByteString`.
I get the following error on the last line:

```
 • Could not deduce: Data.GI.Base.Overloading.CheckForAncestorType
                          Pixbuf
                          gi-gdkpixbuf-2.0.29:GI.GdkPixbuf.Objects.Pixbuf.Pixbuf
                          (Data.GI.Base.Overloading.ParentTypes Pixbuf)
        arising from a use of ‘windowSetDefaultIcon’
```

1. Can somebody please explain what this error means in human?
2. Maybe I am converting the `ByteString` into `Pixbuf` incorrectly. Please suggest another way.

UPDATE:
After @Ismor's helpful and correct answer, here is my final code for future googlers:

```
  let myFile = $(embedFile "img/termonad-lambda.png")
  let wordsss = unpack myFile
  img_ptr <- newArray (map CUChar wordsss)
  ccc <- GI.GLib.Structs.Bytes.bytesNewTake (Just myFile)
  pb <- pixbufNewFromBytes ccc ColorspaceRgb False 8 50 50 (50 * 3)
  GI.Gtk.Objects.Window.windowSetIcon win (Just pb)
```

Comment: could you share the whole error? Also, the function [pixbufNewFromData](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gdkpixbuf-2.0.31/docs/GI-GdkPixbuf-Objects-Pixbuf.html#v:pixbufNewFromData) needs one more argument to free the memory, but you are no using it. Maybe you are using `pixbufNewFromData` from library `gtk`, but function `windowSetDefaultIcon` is from library `gi-gtk-hs`, hence you are using two different gtk bindings.

Comment: "hence you are using two different gtk bindings" - Yep, that was the problem. Thank you very much. Please convert your comment to answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Note the part `gi-gdkpixbuf-2.0.29:GI.GdkPixbuf.Objects.Pixbuf.Pixbuf` in the error. Here GHC printed the whole "package:Module.Type" identifier for a type, instead of the shorter "Type". This happens when you are using multiple packages (or different versions of the same package) that define the same "Module.Type" so GHC needs the full name to disambiguate. This is usually means that you are mixing incompatible packages. (It sometimes happens when misusing `cabal install --lib`, for instance.)

Comment: Very helpful piece of information. Thank you, @chi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the type signature you are using `pixbufNewFromData` from package `gtk` whereas `windowSetDefaultIcon` comes from package `gi-gtk-hs`. That means you are depending on two different set of gtk bindings

The package with most downloads is `gtk` but in its [repo](https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs#gtk2hs) they recommend using `gi-gtk-hs` as they are automatic bindings created with GObject introspection, hence more complete bindings.